# Como passar um parâmetro de uma Action para outra Action em um mesmo Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

Preciso enviar um parâmetro de uma action para outra action num mesmo controller, porém o parâmetro fica "zerado". Como posso fazer isso? Abaixo o código que estou fazendo:

```
[Authorize]
public class ItemMaloteController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index(Guid id)
    {
        ViewBag.ItemsMaloteList = _itemMaloteRepository.GetAll()
                                       .Where(x => x.MaloteId.Equals(id)).ToList();

        ViewBag.Malote = _maloteRepository.GetAll()
                         .Where(x => x.Id.Equals(id)).ToList();

        ViewBag.Curso = _cursoRepository.GetAll().ToList();
        ViewBag.Documentos = _documentosRepository.GetAll();
        ViewBag.MaloteId = id;

        return View();
     }

     public IActionResult Create(ItemMalote itemMalote)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return NotFound();

            itemMalote.Id = Guid.NewGuid();            
            _itemMaloteRepository.Register(itemMalote);
            _itemMaloteRepository.SaveChanges();

            var maloteId = _itemMaloteRepository.GetMalote(itemMalote.MaloteId).Select(x => x.MaloteId).ToList();            

            //Aqui eu chamo minha action "Index" e passo o parametro
            return RedirectToAction("Index", maloteId);
        }
}
```

Acontece que quando chega novamente na action "Index" o parâmetro chega "zerado". Já tentei passar via TempData, mas acontece o mesmo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", new { id = maloteId });
```

Com a solução acima dada pelo Pedro você terá como redirecionamento isso:

> /Controller/Index/maloteId

Mas há mais overloads para o método [RedirectToAction](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2). Se precisar redirecionar para a action de outra controller, por exemplo, você pode usar dessa forma:

```
return RedirectToAction("MinhaAction", "MinhaController", id);
```

Mas nessa questão do SOen vi que ainda assim é possível não ser redirecionado e você pode usar também dessa forma, utlizando o [RouteValueDictionary](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.web.routing.routevaluedictionary?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
return RedirectToAction("SuaAction", new RouteValueDictionary(
       new { controller = "SuaController", action = "SuaAction", Id = id }));
```

Ou você pode apenas fazer isso também:

```
return Index(id);
```

Answer (score 1):

Crie um tipo anônimo com o parâmetro `id` que sua `Action Index` está esperando:

```
//Aqui eu chamo minha action "Index" e passo o parametro
return RedirectToAction("Index", new { id = maloteId });
```

Comment: Faltou apenas o return :)

Comment: Verdade, havia me esquecido... Já editei a resposta. Muito obrigado!